# How to replace a word on nth line after multiple pattern matches that are on different lines?

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I'm trying to find out if there is a way I can use SED or AWK to replace a word under nested certain conditions. Example code:

```cpp
void className::functName1_testName1_paramA()
{
     some_code;
    /* comment */
    returnType_1 paramA  = value1;
    returnType_2 paramB  = value2;
    returnType_3 paramC  = value3;
}

void className::functName1_testName2_paramB()
{
    some_code;
    /* comment */
    returnType_1 paramA  = value1;
    returnType_2 paramB  = value2;
    returnType_3 paramC  = value3;
}

void className::functName2_testName1_paramA()
{
    some_code;
    /* comment */
    returnType_1 paramA  = value1;
    returnType_2 paramB  = value2;
    returnType_3 paramC  = value3;
    returnType_4 paramD  = value4;
}
```

What I'm trying to achieve is

```
IF (functName1 && testName1 && paramA are found/matched) THEN
   IF (returnType_1 && paramA are found/matched in nth line below above match) THEN
      replace value1 with actualValue1;

IF (functName1 && testName2 && paramB are found/matched) THEN
   IF (returnType_2 && paramB are found/matched in nth line below above match) THEN
      replace value2 with actualValue2;

IF (functName2 && testName1 && paramA are found/matched) THEN
   IF (returnType_1 && paramA are found/matched in nth line below above match) THEN
      replace value1 with actualValue1;
```

So on and so forth.

I have templates with a number of combinations of different functNames, testNames, params, and returnTypes so that's what I'd like to be able to match it like the above.

I've thought about using

```
sed '/functName1/ { n; n; n; s/value1/actualValue1/; }' fileName
```

But it wouldn't work because there are so many different cases and the nth lines differ among different functions. So when I was searching for answers, it seemed like people were saying `awk` would be better than `sed` for stuff like this, but I couldn't really find something that's even remotely similar to my case.

I'm assuming there's a way to do it but I'm not so sure. So I guess the question is, is something like this even possible with `awk` or `sed`?

I don't mind writing the `awk`/`sed` command multiple times so if someone can give me an example and the syntax of this `awk`/`sed` command usage, I could just apply the concept and write the rest.

I really appreciate your time and thank you in advance.

Expected output would be something like

```
void className::functName1_testName1_paramA()
{
     some_code;
    /* comment */
    returnType_1 paramA  = actualValue1;  //after being replaced
    returnType_2 paramB  = value2;
    returnType_3 paramC  = value3;
}

void className::functName1_testName2_paramB()
{
    some_code;
    /* comment */
    returnType_1 paramA  = value1;
    returnType_2 paramB  = actualValue2;  //after being replaced
    returnType_3 paramC  = value3;
}

void className::functName2_testName1_paramA()
{
    some_code;
    /* comment */
    returnType_1 paramA  = actualValue1; //after being replaced
    returnType_2 paramB  = value2; 
    returnType_3 paramC  = value3;
    returnType_4 paramD  = value4;
}
```

Comment: What's the expected output?

Comment: Sorry, just added the expected output on the post. Thank you.

Comment: `awk` is designed for these problems. Work thru the [Awk Tutorial](https://grymoire.com/Unix/Awk.html#toc-uh-53) section on patterns and you'll be ready to ask a good Q here. Good luck.

Comment: You do that in sed like `sed '/void className::functName2_testName1_paramB/{ : nextline; n; s/returnType_1 paramA  = value1;/returnType_1 paramA  = actualvalue1;/; t end; b nextline; }; : end;'`. It would require some additional conditions for like `/^}$/b end` exiting the "scope" of the function, so we don't substitute something else, etc.

Comment: Note that it's bad form to specify "do X with A or B" when you don't have a real, underlying *technical* reason to use those specific tools, but just happen to expect that it's what someone would typically use. Even "do X with POSIX-standardized UNIX tools" is better, because it lets the person answering (providing the domain knowledge) determine which specific POSIX-standardized UNIX tools are most fit-to-task.

Comment: @Sweetfinish, Not clear, how come line `functName2_testName1_paramB`'s  `aramB  = actualValue2;` changed? Since you told it should be `IF (functName2 && testName1 && paramA are found/matched) THEN`. Please elaborate more here.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13: I apologize. I mixed up the variables. Good call because it wasn't consistent with what I was trying to explain. Thank you for the catch.

Comment: @Sweetfinish, Could you please check my solution if that worked for you?

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try following, completely based on showed samples only.

```
awk '
!NF{
  found_func2_test1_parama=found_func2_test1_paramb=found_func1_test1_parama=""
}
/functName1_testName1_paramA/{
  found_func1_test1_parama=1
}
/returnType_1 paramA/ && found_func1_test1_parama{
  $NF="actualValue1;"
  sub(/returnType/,"    &")
  print
  next
}
/functName2_testName1_paramB/{
  found_func2_test1_paramb=1
}
found_func2_test1_paramb && /returnType_2 paramB/{
  $NF="actualValue2;"
  sub(/returnType/,"    &")
  print
  next
}
/functName2_testName1_paramA/{
  found_func2_test1_parama=1
}
found_func2_test1_parama && /returnType_1 paramA/{
  $NF="actualValue1;"
  sub(/returnType/,"    &")
  print
  next
}
1
'   Input_file
```